# Percentage difference between two signals

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, percentage

Apologies in advance for what I imagine is a simple question, however I can't work out how to do this.

I have two signals of the same type but with different sensor types, the figure below will give you an idea of some of the data I've got:

[image]

I very simply want to calculate the average percentage difference between the two signals. Methods I've attempted so far have calculated outrageous results, in the order of ~200% difference. My attempt is below:

```
  for i = 1:length(data)
      per(i) = abs((var1(i)-var2(i))/((var1(i)+var2(i))/2)) * 100;
  end
```

I believe the problem in this method is that I'm only calculating the difference between the two immediate points in question (i) and not on a grand scale of all the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about DSP and belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: The problem is not in the implementation (although you don't need a loop for what you are doing). Can you give the exact mathematical formula that you wish to use?

Comment: @Jigg, no, this is what I'm asking. I have been looking around and feel that RMS could be used, but again I'm unsure on implementing it. Thanks.

Comment: Near 0, you are going to get huge outrageous error levels that are throwing off your whole calculation.  This isn't really a question of software programming.  This is a question of defining the problem you are trying to solve in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that this is no Matlab problem but more a problem of how to calculate it. I'll give a short answer because I think that it takes the same time for me now to lament or to write my opinion about the problem.

I recommend to use another metric which is not your percent.

Further I don't think that you have to calculate that metric for each point in your plot and watch it separately for each sample. Instead you could calculate a metric which describes the deviation of the whole two signals.

For example you could calculate the sum of square errors (maybe divided by the number of samples...):

```
sum((data1-data2).^2)/length(data1)
```

where data1 and data2 are the two arrays containing your two signals.

The smaller the error, the smaller the difference between the two signals. And yes, this scale wouldn't be limited to 0...100%

For the Root Mean Square Error you would have to put that into a sqrt(...)

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is wrong if it's root mean squared error that you are after. I would suggest using this code instead:

```
RMSE = sqrt(mean((var1-var2).^2));
```

That will give you the RMSE in your unit of acceleration.